# Getting all installed applications with Category.LAUNCHER

Tags: java, android

My Problem:
I want to get all installed applications with the `Intent Category` `Category.LAUNCHER`.
So I want to get all apps that would be displayed in the Launcher
and then resolve the package and the name.
Such as `package: "com.android.phone" -- name: "Phone"`

My code basically works, but i think, no i **know** this can be made easier:

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent main = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> packages = pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);

for (ResolveInfo resolve_info : packages)
{
    try
    {
        //THIS TWO
        String package_name = resolve_info.activityInfo.packageName;
        String app_name = (String)pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(package_name, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

        Log.i("TEST", "package = <" + package_name + "> name = <" + app_name + ">");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //package not found -- should never happen
    }
}
```

So is there a **better / faster or easier** way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876000/getting-all-installed-applications-with-category-launcher

I had the same question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();

final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List<IntentFilter> outFilters = new ArrayList<IntentFilter>();
outFilters.add(filter);

List<ComponentName> outActivities = new ArrayList<ComponentName>();
pm.getPreferredActivities(outFilters, outActivities, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent startupIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startupIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    PackageManager pm =  this.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(startupIntent, 0);
    Log.i(TAG, "Found " + activities.size() + " activities.");
```

in MainActivity which extends AppCompatActivity or Activity